# Why I am not able to click on next button and forgot password link, please?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]In the below code, the last line where I try to click on forgot password link is not working. I am not able to click on forgot password link.

```
package testpackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class testclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:/chromedriver.exe");//Better place this in a desktop
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
//System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
driver.findElement(By.name("identifier")).sendKeys("j.jagadeesh.1989");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='identifierNext']/content/span")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("forgotPassword")).click();

}
}
```

Comment: Please explain *not working*

Comment: Hi, the last line of my code where I try to click forgot password link is not working. Code: "driver.findElement(By.id("forgotPassword")).click();"

Comment: Again, *not working* doesn't mean anything. You need to explain what is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I have given the correct element(ID) for forgot password link, but the code couldn't identify that, should I have to put wait. I have attached the screenshot of eclipse error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='view_container']/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/button")).click();
```

Try with this.
It will open the forget password page.

Just replace the forget password id with give id and it will work.

I tried this and it worked.

Comment: Thanks!, Works fine driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='forgotPassword']")).click();